# How to fix a runtime error "You must supply a layout_width attribute." in android?

Tags: android, runtime-error

I have an android app which compiles in AndroidStudio, but when I call a certain activity I get the following error:

```
11-22 16:08:40.461 13796-13796/com.impyiablue.stoxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.impyiablue.stoxx, PID: 13796
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.impyiablue.stoxx/com.impyiablue.stoxx.EditEntryActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:606)
at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6422)
at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6591)
at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1866)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1778)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:62)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:808)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.impyiablue.stoxx.EditEntryActivity.onCreate(EditEntryActivity.java:51)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704) 
11-22 16:10:02.231 15805-15805/com.impyiablue.stoxx:remote E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.impyiablue.stoxx:remote, PID: 15805
                                                                             java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "N/A"
                                                                                 at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                                 at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
                                                                                 at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:323)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
                                                                                 at com.impyiablue.stoxx.Tools.ServiceStock$ResponseListener.onResponse(ServiceStock.java:86)
                                                                                 at com.impyiablue.stoxx.Tools.ServiceStock$ResponseListener.onResponse(ServiceStock.java:71)
                                                                                 at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:67)
                                                                                 at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                                                 at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

The corresponding xml file can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/02052d874332eae1ed4d9f6bd605682c). I do not see any problems with this xml file. So how to fix the problem? I also did a clean before the latest build...

Comment: I think  android:layout_weight must be an int?

Comment: Your first TextView does not have any size defined. And I am pretty sure that Android Studio points that out.

Comment: Add `layout_height` and `layout_width` attributes to all the widgets in your XML.

Comment: Don't link to your layout off-site. Include the necessary portions in the question itself.

Comment: But it worked before....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at line 25 of your XML layout, the `TextView` with the `textTitleEdit` ID is missing the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes, which are required. The next `TextView` is missing the same attributes as well.

Comment: @Alex Before when? What did you change? I know those attributes are not required for views within a `GridLayout`, but they are required within a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: The only change I made had absolutely nothing to do with this piece of code. But this always is with me: I am trying to do a very little, trivial change that cannot go wrong, and I have to ask many many questions in the forum. It is ALWAYS the same with me...

Comment: Maybe you know a good tutorial on learning these different layouts? Which attributes are needed, which are optional, which are not needed. It also looks to me this changes quiet often

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski brings up a good point. Do you not have [lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html) enabled? These errors should be highlighted in the editor before compilation. Lint *should* be enabled by default.

Comment: Can I do that in the settings?

Comment: @Alex I don't think so. As far as I know, lint has to be [explicitly suppressed](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings), it's not a simple "on/off" toggle. Check to make sure your build doesn't contain a `lint.xml` file, or a `lintOptions` object in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I will do that later maybe when I am more experienced with android.

Comment: @Alex Lint *should be* on by default. If you are not getting syntax/error highlighting in your code and/or xml files you will have to compile and/or run the project to find any errors. I **highly** suggest making sure lint is enabled, it will only hurt your workflow if it isn't.

Comment: I guess lint is activated. I usually get sometimes code highlighting, but in this case I only got a bit of a red on the right side of the AndroidStudio, where you have to guess where the error might be...

Comment: @Alex you should be able to click on the little red tags to jump right to the error. Then the error should be underlined in red.

Answer (score 3):

> I have an android app which compiles in AndroidStudio

Project compilation **does not** guarantee its correctness and this also includes layouts. Also even i.e. `layout_width` is mandatory for the object at runtime, lack of such during compilation is not a bug, however it is usually result of ommision/mistake. You may simply need to ommit such attributes on purpose, willing to add them later at runtime from running code. No compiler/static analyser will be able to figure this out, so that's why lint will complain, but compilation phase won't fail.

To avoid such problems you may try to use `lint` tool, to catch all the potential issues, however agaim, lack of given attribute is not an error therefore it will not cause any compilation errors. `layout_height` and `layout_width` are mandatory at runtime, so ViewGroup knows how to layout all the childs, and as most of your `TextView`'s neither provide any of these directly nor indirectly, via styles your layout can be considered faulty.